# Fragment that Contains Gridview that contains Clickable photos (Gallery like)

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, gallery

What I'm trying to create is a fragment that consist of a GridView that is filled with clickable pictures.

I have searched many places..
[Normal Grid](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)
[GridView Frag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914627/how-to-bind-data-in-gridview-found-in-fragment-in-android-app)

and somehow trying to work them together..but doesn't seem to do that job

///// Activity class /////

```
public static class ChampionFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){

        System.out.println("Inside onCreateView");

        String[] champList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.championList);
        System.out.println("Got champList");

        View champView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.champion_menu, container, false);
        System.out.println("inflater");

        /*
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAptr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.champion_menu,champList);
        System.out.println("Created array Adapter");

        //GridView grid = (GridView)champView.findViewById(R.id.champView);
        System.out.println("Grided");

        grid.setAdapter(arrayAptr);
        System.out.println("Set Adapter");
        */

        return  champView;
        //ArrayList champList = getChampionList();
    }
}
```

///// Layout ////

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/champView"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</GridView>
```

so yeah I've tried many ways...I have no idea how to make it work
help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should set up your data and adapters within a different method

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
```

Then you need to set up an onItemClickLister

```
champView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```